# Creating custom data in Shopify to save into the customer object and access on a different page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, shopify

I am trying to create custom data to save into the customer object, which I could then access on a different page. I have an input like this

```html
<input type="hidden" id="{{ formId }}-score" name=contact[score]>
```

I created an exam page that uses a script to calculate the score, which is then sending the value to that input. I am trying to save that value into the customer object which I could then access on a different page like this:

```html
{% if customer.score > 11 %} <h1> You Passed </h1> {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Shopify, using tags we can save custom data of the customer. You will need to add tags in the name like this: name="customer[tags]"

You can pass the value as per your need like this: value="score_11"

You can fetch the value like this: customer.tags

You can use tags in your condition.
{% if customer.tags > score_11 %}

Comment: Wouldn't this overwrite existing tags? And besides, where do you submit this form with `customer[tags]` field?